# Unique number of possibilities (combinatorics question)?

Tags: combinatorics

I have a combinatorics question in the context of statistics. The context is I have $n$ observations and $k$ clusters (you can assume $k \le n$ ). The total number of ways to assign the observations to clusters (allowing empty clusters) is trivially $k^n$. Each particular assignment is called a particular encoding, but two assignments that have the same groups but different labels (i.e. cluster names) are actually equivalent. In other words, I don't care about the labeling (e.g. if I have two clusters A and B, I don't care which I call A and which I call B). I want the number of unique encodings.

My guess is this number is $\frac{k^n}{k} = k^{n-1}$. Though for some reason I have lingering doubts.

Comment: The number is a sum of Stirling numbers of the second kind.

Comment: By "allowing empty observations" do you mean "allowing empty clusters"? By "the number of unique encodings" do you mean "the number of distinguishable (inequivalent) encodings"? Do you know about [Stirling numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)?

Comment: I don't know about Stirling numbers, but am in the process of reading the wikipedia page on them now. I meant to say "empty clusters" not observations, sorry about that. Yes I mean the 'number of distinguishable encodings when I say unique encodings.

Comment: I suppose I was using misleading examples with 2 clusters to get my proposed solution. To make sure I understand correctly if I wanted the number of unique encoders for k = 3 and n = 4, I would do S2(4,3) + S2(4,2) + S2(4,1) = 14?

Comment: Yes, if I understand your question. In other words, $6+7+1=14$ is the number of different ways a set of $4$ elements can be partitioned into **at most** $3$ (unlabeled) classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can asign observations to clusters in $k^n$ ways, and you can label (reorder) the clusters in $k!$ ways, for a total of $\frac{k^n}{k!}$ (this assumes that you consider empty clusters are to be considered different). If the empty cluster names are irrelevant, you want the ways of partitioning your observations into at most $k$ labeled (order is important) classes, i.e.,
$$
\sum_{1 \le r \le k} \genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{}{n}{r}
$$

Comment: Why is the $r!$ in the summation needed?

Comment: The Stirling numbers count the ways to divide into $r$ partitions, they can be reordered in $r!$ ways.

Comment: Why do reorderings matter if the classes are 'unlabeled'? For a simple case of k = 2 and n = 4 (4 observations into 2 clusters), one could enumerate the 16 possibilities if you call the clusters A and B, and it's not hard to see there are only 8 unique encodings. However, if one uses the formula with r! one gets $2! * S_2(4,2) + 3! * S_2(4,3) = 50$, which is incorrect.

Comment: @Grid, brain glitch. Fixing. Thanks!